# CSS3 Transform Translate to the left

Tags: css, animation, translate-animation

I have titles that I want to add CSS3 animation to it

I want to transform

**Title**

to

**[Title]**

And I want the square brackets to animate from the center of the word to the borders of it with animation.

something like..

**Ti[]tle**

to

**[Title]**

with animation (ofcourse i'm using `:before` `:after` to add the brackets with `opacity` 0 to 1)

my p style:

```
p:before {
    content: "[";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%; /*to add the bracket to the center of the word*/
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
```

Thank You !

Comment: and what's your question? what's wrong with the code?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan this is the starting style, i'm still missing the translate class,, this style adds the square bracket to the center of the word, I want to translate the bracket to the left of the word

Comment: Why do you need to translate it when you are positioning it..why not just transition/animate the position value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
p {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
}

p:before,
p:after{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

p:before {
    content: "[";
    left: 50%;
}

p:after {
    content: "]";
    right: 50%;
}

p:hover:before {
    left: -5px;
    opacity: 1;
}

p:hover:after {
    right: -5px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>Title</p>

<p>A Longer Title</p>
```

Comment: exactly, but you are putting exact pixels values, the point is that I don't know the size of the word, thx for the reply

Comment: The size of the word is is irrelevant. the -5px will position the brackets 5px from the end of the word no matter how long it is

Comment: This solution forces you to hover the element to see animation. Refer to my answer for automatic animation.

Comment: @Sebastien this is already what I wanted, thx for your answer as well

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

with this html:

```
<div>
<a href="" class="link4">TESTING</a>
</div>
```

and these css's:

```
div{
        padding: 18px 0 18px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
a {
    color: #999;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:before, a:after {
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
}

a:before {
    margin-right: 10px;
    content: '[';
    -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -1px);
    -moz-transform: translate(20px, -1px);
    transform: translate(20px, -1px);
    vertical-align: top;
}

a:after {
    margin-left: 10px;
    content: ']';
    -webkit-transform: translate(-20px, -1px);
    -moz-transform: translate(-20px, -1px);
    transform: translate(-20px, -1px);
}

a:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -1px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, -1px);
    transform: translate(0px, -1px);
}
a:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -1px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, -1px);
    transform: translate(0px, -1px);
}
```

You get this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/3ydukgy9/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using frame animations. This way you won't have to hover the element (or anything else) for the animation to start.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Paf_Sebastien/j2cvagjf/

Set `:before` and `:after` like this :

```
h1:before {
    content: "[";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-animation: bracketleft 1s 1 forwards;
    animation: bracketleft 1s 1 forwards;
}
```

Then handle the animation :

```
@-webkit-keyframes bracketleft {
  0%   { opacity: 0; left: 50%; }
  100% { opacity: 1; left:-10px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bracketright {
  0%   { opacity: 0; right: 50%; }
  100% { opacity: 1; right: -10px; }
}
```